# GoogleMaps api : why does my map state become null?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Help appreciated, I'm stuck !

**What I try to do**
I display a Google map with a set of marker.
When I click on a marker, I want to add a Google circle to the map.

**What happens**
When I click on a first marker, no circle is displayed.
But when I click on a second marker and more, they are displayed !

**Why it does not work**
I've tracked the map state value with console.log.
The problem is that when I first go to the MarkkerClicked function, for an unknown reason, the "map" state's value is "null" ! So no circle is created.
And, even stranger, the map state contains a map instance when the map is first loaded, and also when I click a second marker.

Can you tell me what I have done wrong, that makes the map value set to null when the first marker is clicked ?

My component :

```
import { GoogleMap, MarkerF, useJsApiLoader } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

let mapCircle1 = null

export default function MapPage() {
  // The array of markers is in the REDUX store
  const selectMarkersArray = state => state.markersArray
  const markersArray = useSelector(selectMarkersArray)

  // This state contains the selected marker (or null if no marker selected)
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);

  // Options for GoogleMaps
  let center = {
      lat: 43.3318,
      lng: 5.0550
  }
  let zoom = 15
  const containerStyle = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%"
  }

  // GoogleMaps loading instructions
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
      id: 'google-map-script',
      googleMapsApiKey: "MY-GOOGLE-KEY"
  })
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)
  const onLoad = useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setMap(map)
    console.log('map value in onLoad :')
    console.log(map)
  }, [])
  const onUnmount = useCallback(function callback(map) {
  setMap(null)
  }, [])

  // Function executed when a marker is clicked
  function markerClicked(props) {
    console.log('map value in markerClicked :')
    console.log(map)

    // I create a new Circle data
    let circleOption1 = {
      fillColor: "#2b32ac ",
      map: map,
      center: {lat:props.marker.spotLatitude, lng:props.marker.spotLongitude},
      radius: props.marker.spotCircleRadius,
    };
    mapCircle1 = new window.google.maps.Circle(circleOption1);

    // I update the selecte marker state
      setSelectedMarker({...props.marker})
    }
    return (isLoaded ? (
      <Box height="80vh" display="flex" flexDirection="column">
        <GoogleMap 
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={zoom}                
          onLoad={onLoad}
          onUnmount={onUnmount}
        >
          {markersArray.map((marker, index) => {
            return (
              <MarkerF 
                key={index.toString()} 
                position={{lat:marker.spotLatitude, lng:marker.spotLongitude}}
                onClick={() => markerClicked({marker:marker})}
                >
              </MarkerF>
            )
          })}
        </GoogleMap>
      </Box>
    ) : <></>
  )
};
```

And the console.log (first log when the map is loaded, second when the first marker is clicked, third when another marker is clicked):

````
map value in onLoad :
jj {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: hda, gm_accessors_: {…}, mapCapabilities: {…}, renderingType: 'UNINITIALIZED', …}

map value in markerClicked :
null

map value in markerClicked :
jj {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: hda, gm_accessors_: {…}, mapCapabilities: {…}, renderingType: 'RASTER', …}```
````

Comment: You should probably not expose an unrestricted API key here on Stack overflow...

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox / codepen or alike?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've never done this, I will try !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It coulds be because you are not using State Hooks and the `<Circle />` component for rendering / updating circles

I was able to reproduce your code on codesandbox and confirmed that the `map` is indeed returning `null` per marker click. I'm still unsure as to why it really is happening, but I managed to fix it and managed to render a circle even on the first marker click, after modifying your code by utilizing **State Hooks** for your circles, and also using the `<Circle />` component as per the [react-google-maps/api library docs](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#circle).

I just managed to hardcode some stuff since I did not use redux to reproduce your code but one of the things I did is create a `circles` array State Hook:

```
  // this array gets updated whenever you click on a marker
  const [circles, setCircles] = useState([
    {
      id: "",
      center: null,
      circleOptions: {
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        clickable: false,
        draggable: false,
        editable: false,
        visible: true,
        radius: 100,
        zIndex: 1
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Just make sure to add the `useState` on your import.

Then for demonstration, I hardcoded a markers array:

```
  // This could be your array of marker using redux,
  // I just hardcoded this for demonstration
  const markersArray = [
    {
      id: 1,
      position: { lat: 43.333194, lng: 5.050184 }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      position: { lat: 43.336356, lng: 5.053353 }
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      position: { lat: 43.331609, lng: 5.056403 }
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      position: { lat: 43.328806, lng: 5.058998 }
    }
  ];
```

Then here's my `markerClicked` function looks like:

```
// Function executed when a marker is clicked
  const markerClicked = (marker) => {
    console.log("map value on marker click: ");
    console.log(map);
    // This stores the marker coordinates
    // in which we will use for the center of your circle
    const markerLatLng = marker.latLng.toJSON();
    // this will update our circle array
    // adding another object with different center
    // the center is fetched from the marker that was clicked
    setCircles((prevState) => {
      return [
        ...prevState,
        {
          id: "",
          center: markerLatLng,
          circleOptions: {
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            clickable: false,
            draggable: false,
            editable: false,
            visible: true,
            radius: 100,
            zIndex: 1
          }
        }
      ];
    });
    // this is for you to see that the circles array is updated.
    console.log(circles);
  };
```

Please do note that the `onClick` attribute for `<MarkerF />` automatically returns a parameter that includes the marker's coordinates and other stuff, you can just try to use `console.log` if you wanna check. Also make sure that the value you put on the `onClick` is equals to the name of the function alone. In this case, it is `markerClicked`, you'll see later on.

Note: I also added a `mapClicked` function for you to be able to clear the circles array.

*`Please see proof of concept sandbox below.`*

Then this is how I rendered the `<GoogleMap />` component with `<MarkerF />` and `<Circle />` components as its children.

```
    <GoogleMap
      mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
      center={center}
      zoom={zoom}
      onLoad={onLoad}
      onUnmount={onUnmount}
      onClick={mapClicked}
    >
      {markersArray.map((marker, index) => {
        return (
          <MarkerF
            key={index.toString()}
            position={{ lat: marker.position.lat, lng: marker.position.lng }}
            onClick={markerClicked}
          ></MarkerF>
        );
      })}
      {/* This maps through the circles array, so when the array gets updated,
       another circle is added */}
      {circles.map((circle, index) => {
        return (
          <Circle
            key={index.toString()}
            // required
            center={circle.center}
            // required
            options={circle.circleOptions}
          />
        );
      })}
    </GoogleMap>
```

With all these, the map value on marker click does not return null, and a circle gets rendered even on first marker click.

Here's a proof of concept sandbox for you to check and see how it works ( ***Make sure to use your own API key to test*** ): https://codesandbox.io/s/proof-of-concept-show-circle-on-marker-click-s175wl?file=/src/Map.js

> *Note: There's some weird offset between the marker and the circle if you zoom out too far, but seems fine when you zoom in. I have encountered this on some previous questions here in SO when rendering polylines and I don't know why is that or how to fix it.*

With that said, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the attention paid to my issue, the time spent on it, and your perfect answer. It works perfectly. I still don't know why my map value was null at first, but whatever the reason, now it works. Thank you!